# Codeigniter Database Insert - Not Working With Array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to insert some data into a database via codeigniter but am getting some strange errors. Does anyone know the cause:

My insert array ($datainsert) is the following when printed:

```
Array ( [online_name] => Discount Store 
        [online_nameKey] => d 
        [storeGroup_ID] => 
        [CJ_ID] => 123456 
        [online_tag] => Health and Medical 
        [online_businessType] => 0 
        [online_businessTypeSub] => 0 
        [online_homepage] => http://www.discountstore.com 
        [store_ChainID] => 
        [savingsdotcom_ID] => 0 )
```

Trying to print the insert I use:

```
echo $DB1->_insert('stores_online', $datainsert);
```

Which results in:

```
INSERT INTO stores_online (Discount Store, d, , 123456, Health and Medical, 0, 0, http://www.discountstore.com, , 0) VALUES ()
```

I can't figure out why its not using the array keys for the first () and the values correctly.

Comment: What 'strange errors' are you getting?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: It's just shooting out a 500 DB error, even if I have all errors set to display and throw it in a try/catch loop. But it is clear that the insert statement is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$datainsert=Array ( [online_name] => Discount Store,
                    [online_nameKey] => d,
                    [storeGroup_ID] => something,
                    [CJ_ID] => 123456 ,
                    [online_tag] => Health and Medical ,
                    [online_businessType] => 0 ,
                    [online_businessTypeSub] => 0 ,
                    [online_homepage] => http://www.discountstore.com ,
                    [store_ChainID] => ,
                    [savingsdotcom_ID] => 0 
                 ) ;

$this->db->insert('stores_online', $datainsert);
```

Comment: That won't work as it would attempt to insert into a slave database, which is why I am using $DB1 which specifies the master database.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->db->insert('stores_online', $datainsert);
```

instead of

```
echo $DB1->_insert('stores_online', $datainsert);
```

Comment: _insert prints the resulting query for debugging purposes

Comment: If you want to check the query then you should use -                     $this->db->last_query();

Comment: I can't get to that point because the program crashes on the query.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is over a year, but I had the same issue and I solve it by creating the query manually this way:

```
public function add($data)
{
    $query = 'INSERT INTO myTable (';

    // (Column1, Column2, Column3,
    foreach($data as $key => $column)
        $query .= $key . ',';

    // Removes the last comma 
    // Column3, == Column3) VALUES(
    $query .= rtrim($query, ',') . ') VALUES(';

    // Value1, Value2, Value3,
    foreach($data as $key => $column)
        $query .= "'" . $column . "',";

    // Removes the last comma and closes the query
    $query .= rtrim($query, ',') . ')';

    // Result: INSERT INTO (Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3')
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done:

`echo $DB1->_insert('stores_online', array_keys($datainsert), $datainsert);`

P.S. This works for CI 2.X and I have not tested it for other version of CI.